# Polars - use is_in() with durations

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe with a column containing a set of durations, like 5m, 15m, etc...

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "duration_m": [5, 15, 30]
})
df = df.with_columns(
    duration = pl.duration( minutes = pl.col("duration_m"))
)
df

shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ duration_m ┆ duration     │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ i64        ┆ duration[ns] │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 5          ┆ 5m           │
│ 15         ┆ 15m          │
│ 30         ┆ 30m          │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

I want to filter this dataframe to return only rows that are 5m or 15m using is_in().
However, when I do this:

```
my_durations = [pl.duration(minutes=5), pl.duration(minutes=15)]
df.filter(pl.col("duration").is_in(my_durations))
```

I get:

> ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type

This has no error (but is obviously not what I want to do):

```
df.filter(pl.col("duration").is_in(pl.duration(minutes=5)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `.is_in` does not support `list[Expr]` e.g. `pl.col("duration_m").is_in([pl.lit(5), pl.lit(10)])` also fails. Not sure if this is supposed to work or not. `pl.any_horizontal(pl.col("duration") == d for d in my_durations)` is a potential workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, even though `pl.duration` is an Expr and `.is_in` accepts expressions that it errors out. My best guess is that it sees a python list first so it assumes away getting an expression. From there it doesn't get a python type that it knows what to do with and just sees an object.

Causes aside, you have **two ways to get around this**.

**The first:**
If you wrap your list in a `pl.concat_list` then you still have an expression instead of a python list but that won't be enough because it doesn't broadcast that to the whole df so you'll get an error about size mismatch which you can also fix by wrapping that in `pl.repeat` like this:

```
df.filter(pl.col('duration')
          .is_in(pl.repeat(pl.concat_list(my_durations), pl.count()))
          )
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ duration_m ┆ duration     │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ i64        ┆ duration[ns] │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 5          ┆ 5m           │
│ 15         ┆ 15m          │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

That's awfully clunky, better to just use the second method.

**The second:**
Just use `timedelta` instead of `duration` when you're not setting it with the values in a df like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
my_durations = [timedelta(minutes=5), timedelta(minutes=15)]
df.filter(pl.col("duration").is_in(my_durations))
```

**As an aside...**

if you start with

```
my_durations = [pl.duration(minutes=5), pl.duration(minutes=15)]
```

then you can get the same `timedelta` list by doing:

```
[pl.select(x).item() for x in my_durations]
```

Comment: Ha. That second one is surprisingly simple and odd that you actually have to use it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can only apply `is_in` to a list or Series of concrete objects, which `pl.duration` does not construct (it creates an `Expr`). But as far as I can tell, getting a list or Series of durations is tricky. You have two options: the polars-only route, where you construct this Series using nothing but polars primitives; or you can just construct a list directly from `datetime.timedelta`, which is what polars uses under the hood.

### Option 1

```py
filter_df = pl.DataFrame({"duration_m": [5, 15]})
    .with_columns(duration = pl.duration(minutes="duration_m"))

df.filter(pl.col("duration").is_in(filter_df.get_column("duration")))
```

### Option 2

```py
import datetime
filter_list = [datetime.timedelta(seconds = 60*t) for t in [5, 15]]
df.filter(pl.col("duration").is_in(filter_list))
```

### Result (for both)

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ duration_m ┆ duration     │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ i64        ┆ duration[ns] │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 5          ┆ 5m           │
│ 15         ┆ 15m          │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: thank you @BallpointBen I took the pandas detour as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

[`.any_horitzontal`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal) could also be a workaround:

```py
df.filter(
   pl.any_horizontal(
      pl.col("duration") == duration
      for duration in my_durations
   )
)
```

`map()` with `Expr.eq`:

```py
df.filter(
   pl.any_horizontal(
      map(pl.col("duration").eq, my_durations)
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ duration_m ┆ duration     │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ i64        ┆ duration[ns] │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 5          ┆ 5m           │
│ 15         ┆ 15m          │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```